# How to replace the json content with external file?

Tags: javascript

I need to separate the big config file with different local JSON file. I wonder how can I bring the different JSON file as part of the config file? The config file is also a JSON object. But it has a very big attribute, each of them has over 300 lines code. I need to separate them as a local JSON file to make the config file look like much more simple. Details of the code as below:

```
module.exports = function ()  {
  this.nodeServer = 
  this.tiledLayerBaseURL = 
  this.featureLayerBaseURL = 
  this.TIME_TO_IDLE = 10; // If user has no action within 1 minute, enter idle phase
  this.TIME_TO_LOGOUT = 3600; // Force user to logout after one hour idle phase
  this.Scenarios = [
    //Too many code for each scenario, over 200 lines of code
    //Need to separate them to local json file
    //I wonder how can I include these separated json file as part of code here
    {
      scenarioName: "Canada",
      scenarioID: 1,
      thumbnail_url: "/assets/img/scenario1_icon.png",
      isActive: true,
      scenarioExtent: [],
      scenarioHeight: "1111",
      baseMap: "satellite",
      indoorBaseMap: "streets-night-vector",
      ground: "world-elevation",
      timezone: "GMT-0600 (MDT)",
      init_camera_pos: {
        center: [-114.134, 51.084],
        heading: 0,
        tilt: 0,
        zoom: 16,
        zoomZvalue:2500
      },
      ...
      ...
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `Scenarios.js` file that contains your array of scenarios. Then import that into your config file.

```
// Scenarios.js
module.exports = [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  // etc
]

// Config file
import scenarios from "./Scenarios.js" // or use require()
module.exports = function () {
  // etc
  this.Scenarios = scenarios;
}
```